# Multiple datasource in combobox?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, linq, ado.net

i'm using DevExpress now. Now i want to add Combobox with each item is one datasource. Example: I have 2 items in combobox.

If i choose item 1 with querystring is "SElect * from my table1" and bind in Gridview

If i choose item 2 with querystring is "SElect * from my table2" and bind in Gridview

Anyone could help me please, i really need in my project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that the combo box item text is the `SELECT` statement and when you select an item you need it to run that `SELECT` statement and bind the results to a `DataGridView`? ***Also,*** please post the code that fills the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that pops to mind is to create a list add them to the list then bind that list to combobox.

```
List<string> Mylist = new List<string>();
string item1 = //returned value from query
 Mylist.add(item1);

string item2 = //returned value from query
 Mylist.add(item2);

 MycomboBox.DataSource = MyList;
 MyComboBox.DataBind();
```

I am assuming somthing like that is what you mean based on what I read. If this is not please clarify the question.